# How to recover fitted values from BSTS poisson model (in R)?

Tags: r, time-series, poisson, state-space

I am trying to recover in-sample predictions (fitted values) from a bsts model  with a specified poisson response using the `bsts` package in `R`. The following results in an error: `Prediction errors are not supported for Poisson or logit models`.

```
data("AirPassengers")
# 11 years, monthly data (timestep=monthly) --> 132 observations
Y <- stats::window(AirPassengers, start=c(1949,1), end=c(1959,12))
y <- log10(Y)

ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(), y)
ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, y, nseasons=12, season.duration=1)
bsts.model <- bsts(Y, state.specification=ss, niter=150, family='poisson')


bsts.prediction.errors(bsts.model)
```

Is there a way to retrieve predictions on model-training data with a poisson model in bsts?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to extract the contribution of each model component at time t and sum them.

```
get_yhats2 <- function(fit){
  burn <- SuggestBurn(0.1, fit)
  X     <- fit$state.contributions
  niter <- dim(X)[1]
  ncomp <- dim(X)[2]
  nobs  <- dim(X)[3]
  
  # initialize final fit/residuals matrices with zeros
  predictions <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = niter - burn, ncol = nobs)
  p0 <- predictions
  
  comps <- seq_len(ncomp)
  for (comp in comps) {
    # pull out the state contributions for this component and transpose to
    # a niter x (nobs - burn) array
    compX <- X[-seq_len(burn), comp, ]
    
    # accumulate the predictions across each component
    predictions <- predictions + compX
  }
  
  return(predictions)
}

get_yhats2(bsts.model)
```

But I also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72118200/two-methods-of-recovering-fitted-values-from-a-bayesian-structural-time-series-m), showing that this method didn't necessarily match expectations I had even in the Gaussian case.